Common code conflict with multiple JMS listeners invoked at same time
We have a springboot application which contains multiple JMS listeners reading message from different destinations. The application has a common logging framework which provides methods to log specific values  taken from input message from each listener class and log the same in a file system as a single line per record.
We have found that the logs are getting mixed with values from both listeners when the message is received by both listeners at the same time. the log framework class is autowired in both listeners but there is an initialize of values/maps/objects at the start of every txn.
The JMS listener is connecting to IBM MQ.
It seems the JMS listeners are sharing the same thread hence, the values are shared. I tried to assign different connection factory, taskExecutors used synchronized keywords inside listener class, used concurrentMaps to store log values, but none of the method seems to be working.
The ask is how to assign different threads from start to individual listeners or any more inputs how to make the logging framework (methods) thread-safe.
Thanks
Edited to provide more information:
By enabling logging can confirm that JMS listeners are using different threads.
thread id ------398 name o.s.j.jlec#0-1
thread id ------401 name v2-4
04:13:17.907 [v2-4] INFO  c.test.LogTransactions - springboot-test-app|946144f5|{listener="BatchPCListener", thread="o.s.j.jlec#0-1", operation="listener-1-logs"}|
04:13:17.930 [o.s.j.jlec#0-1] INFO  c.test.LogTransactions - springboot-test-app|946144f5|{listener="BatchPCListener", thread="o.s.j.jlec#0-1", operation="listener-2-logs"}|

here listener=BatchPCListener is copied from previous thread v2-4 to thread o.s.j.jlec. The correct value is RealTimePCListener.
Another observation is the operation="listener-2-logs" for o.s.j.jlec thread is getting updated. Ideally it should also have been copied.

The code that is either setting or displaying listener= isn't thread safe. Unless you show that code, it is very difficult to tell why.

That you are seeing an interweaving of log output from both listeners implies that they are more than likely running in separate threads.
If they were using the same thread, then you would expect there to be more of a cluster pattern as one listener pauses to allow the other some cpu time.
The most likely explanation is that your log framework class isn't thread safe, and the second thread is overwriting the values of the first thread. If you share your logging code, or at least how you are autowiring it, it may be possible to identify what is making it thread unsafe.
You can add getId() into your log messages, which will show the thread id the message is being logged from, providing you are getting the thread id each time. If you are caching it for the logging then that may be non-reentrant.

Thank you looking into this. I did few more digging and logging the thread id, it seems yes they are using different threads but the data from first thread is being used. More interesting part is that for some fields value are changing but for some it is retaining the same value of the first thread. I am posting some example log txns in the main question.
